# How to open a modal window

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to pop up a modal window after a series of IFs. Let's say that I have a form, I take the inputs, process them (in another page) and, if everything goes well, the modal window pops up and says 'Thanks for registering!'. So what I have been working with so far is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) { ...
```

to triger that I can use

```
<a href="#dialog" name="modal">lalala</a>

<div id="boxes">
<div id="dialog" class="window">
Simple Modal Window |<a href="#" class="close"/> Close</a>
</div>
```

However, I don't want to have to click on a link to open the modal window but after an IF is valid. So tried to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div[id=modal]').click(function(e) { ...
```

and modified the html:

```
<div id="modal" href="#dialog">lalala

<div id="boxes">
<div id="dialog" class="window">
Simple Modal Window |
<a href="#" class="close"/> Seguir</a>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

(Can be checked at http://pasionesargentas.webatu.com/test4.php)
But ended up in the same spot (having to click in lalala). Nothing happened If I change .click for .bind o .trigger.
Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps instead of assigning the click handler to the link you want to capture some variable in the page the modal should pop. This variable could be a query string with confirmation of processing the data from previous form or even a hidden field. Then you capture the variable and *then* you execute the logic to open the pop up window.

Comment: well, I didn't think about it that way. i am pretty new in JS/jQuery so I have to dig deeper in that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the code as is and add a $.trigger() call to mimic a click event without having to actually click the div like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modal').click(function(e){
        ...
    });
    $('#modal').trigger('click');
});
```

However as Thiago mentioned above, you should consider using a query string or hidden field of some sort to indicate if the form has been processed correctly on the previous page.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear on my explanation. I basically send an email with a link, so the user opens that page (with a hash) and he is able to add a password to the account for the very first time. After he completes that form and submits it I make sure that new pass is long enough, the two pass are equal, etc (everything checked in the same page). If everything goes well I proceed to save it in the database (also in the same page) and then I want the window to pop up.

Comment: @cbarg Do you have a function that fires when the password is saved? Are you saving through AJAX?

Comment: After you save, put something like 'success' in a hidden field on the page. Then change your logic so every time the page loads your script checks for that value in the hidden field. If you get the value after posting the page you trigger the click.

Comment: Thanks guys, in the end Ia m going with $('#modal').trigger('click'); for now. However, I am gonna dig deeper in Thiago's suggestion.